# How to resize an animated gif image using C#?

Tags: c#, image, gif, animated-gif

Is there a method to create a copy of an animated gif image using C#?

What I want is to generate a copy of a given gif image using the height and width parameters that the user provides. I have tried for a couple of hours to accomplish this but the resulting image does not preserve the original animations.

Comment: You mean resize correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to loop through the frames in the animated GIF and resize each one.

May also want to take a look at [GifLib](http://www.codeplex.com/GifLib).

Answer (score 6):

Took me a while to find this, but finally found a solution:

Install **Magick.NET** via NuGet, license can be found here:
https://magick.codeplex.com/license

Example code:

```
var newWidth = 100;
using (var collection = new MagickImageCollection(new FileInfo(@"C:\test.gif")))
{
    collection.Coalesce();
    foreach (var image in collection)
    {
        image.Resize(newWidth, 0);
    }
    collection.Write(@"c:\resized.gif");
}
```

From my tests, this works with alpha channels and varying frame rates.  Seems to be perfect!

Comment: I had to remove the call to Coalesce() to get this to work. Also, if you want to resize locally, replace Write() with ToBitmap(ImageFormate.Gif). Also, this is **extremely** slow. Not recommended for real-time applications where speed is needed.

Answer (score 2):

In case it helps someone in the future, I have found another solution that is much faster than Magick.NET (in processing the same gif, it takes only 3s instead of 50-60s than Magick.NET takes)

[PhotoSauce.MagicScaler](https://github.com/saucecontrol/PhotoSauce) (Only work with Windows (.NET Core and .NET 5+) and [partially works on Linux](https://github.com/saucecontrol/PhotoSauce/issues/16#issuecomment-616182080))

Example:

```
MagicImageProcessor.ProcessImage(@"\img\big.jpg", @"\img\small.jpg", new ProcessImageSettings { Width = 400 });
```

Resize with Bytes (Tested with png, jpg and gif):

```
public static byte[] ResizeImageBytes(byte[] imageBytes, int newWidth, int newHeight) {
    using (MemoryStream outStream = new()) {
        ProcessImageSettings processImageSettings = new() {
            Width = newWidth,
            Height = newHeight,
            ResizeMode = CropScaleMode.Stretch,
            HybridMode = HybridScaleMode.Turbo
        };
        MagicImageProcessor.ProcessImage(imageBytes, outStream, processImageSettings);
        return outStream.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is much faster than Magick.NET. Thx.

Comment: I didn't bother trying anything else as this worked a treat first time. Thank you. Oh... And thanks also for the ReziseImageBytes() method. Exactly what I required. 