# How to resize animated gif file using C#?

Tags: c#

Dear all,
I need to re-size an animated gif file on my provided size, using C#.How can i do that.I search the solution on the google but don't get any proper solution.I already see the atalasoft,codeproject,giflib on codeplex but non of this is proper solution.So, Please help me just re-size an animated gif file using c#.

thanks in advance 
Riad

Comment: quick, simple and dirty would be: download imagemagick and call it by exec ( ` convert -resize ` or something like this)  -> http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php. There's also an imagemagick library to use for own programms.

Comment: thanks.But it's a large things.How can i call it using c#.or exactly which file or function should to call? could u pls guide.

Comment: No proper guide line received.can anybody help me pls...is their any image processing functionality have in c# to resize an animated image??..pls guide..

Comment: What isn't appropriate about Atalasoft dotImage?  I wrote sample code for a client that did just that using dotImage.

Comment: could you pls guide me?because atalasoft is a registry product and evaluation time is 30 days?I download the sample code from here http://www.atalasoft.com/kb/article.aspx?id=10086 But it's showing atalasoft.dotimage reference missing.

Comment: You need to install dotImage, request an eval license and set the references to the newly installed assemblies.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/718491/resize-animated-gif-file-without-destroying-animation

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/539034/161052 though neither (at this time) have useful answers.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, no quick-and-dirty method exists.

You will need to split the GIF into separate frames, then re-size each individual frame, then re-assemble the GIF image.

And sorry, I do not have the code to provide you, other than to refer you to [Google](http://www.google.ca/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=c%23+resize+image)

Answer (score 0):

Atalasoft's DotImage should be fine, and they even have [sample code](http://www.atalasoft.com/kb/article.aspx?id=10086#) on their site.

Comment: he said, that he already saw Atalasoft...

Comment: @cevik true, but he hasn't said why it's not a "proper solution" and it's not necessarily immediately obvious that Atalasoft does support animated GIFs. The sample code has to do quite a bit of work rather than just calling a `ResizeAnimatedGif` method. Without seeing that code, you could easily dismiss Alatlasoft when it can actually do the job.

Comment: Dear @stevemegson,I download the code from your provided link.it's not working.then download their Dotimage3.0.Still not work.On C# solution explorer Atalasoft.Image reference missing.so program could not run.to solve the problem i download a registry scanner(By many of google suggestion) and scan my registry.problem still continuing...I search the atalasoft.image.dill file to add on my reference file .But i don't get it any where.Also Atalasoft is a registry product .The evaluation process will be expired within30 dayes.

Comment: The free version of DotImage should be fine, though I'll admit I haven't actually used it. http://www.atalasoft.com/photofree

Comment: thx bro,But it's the trial version.That i already mention already..Is their any other way to solve it?(resize animated gif file)

Comment: There's a 30-day trial of the paid version, but there's also a free version - the installation wizard asks you which you want to do... http://i.imgur.com/Oy43b.png