# Cropping animated GIFs with code

Tags: c#, .net, image, system.drawing, animated-gif

I am usinga piece of code like

```
string originalfilename = Server.MapPath(" ") + "\\img\\" + file_image.FileName;
string originalrelative = "\\img\\" + file_image.FileName;
file_image.SaveAs(originalfilename);
string thumbfilename = Server.MapPath(" ") + "\\img\\t_" + file_image.FileName;
string thumbrelative = "\\img\\t_" + file_image.FileName;
Bitmap original = new Bitmap(originalfilename);
int squareside = 0;
if (original.Width >= original.Height) { squareside = original.Height; } 
 else { squareside = original.Width; }
Bitmap squareimage = (Bitmap)original.Clone(
    new Rectangle(new Point(0, 0), new Size(squareside, squareside)),
    System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.DontCare);
Bitmap thumb = (Bitmap)squareimage.GetThumbnailImage(200, 200,
    new System.Drawing.Image.GetThumbnailImageAbort(ThumbnailCallback),
    IntPtr.Zero);
thumb.Save(thumbfilename);
file_original = file_image.PostedFile.FileName;
file_thumb = "t_"+file_image.PostedFile.FileName;
```

to get thumbnail images of each uploaded picture and I use the thumbnail versions of pictures around the website. How should I manipulate this code to preserve the gif files as animated gif files? When I get thumbnails for animated gifs, this code saves them as normal gifs. Of course bitmap class wouldn't support animated gifs but does .net framework support any alternative?

Comment: What do you mean by thumbnail version of an animated gif? small animated gif?

Comment: @Shoban yes, a small animated gif, just cropped

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to copy an animated gif image using C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/539034/how-to-copy-an-animated-gif-image-using-c) - the answer there is [GifLib](http://www.codeplex.com/GifLib)