# uploading GIF image stream in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, animation, gif

this is my code for uploading images in the database i am resizing the images when i upload it on server side.

```js
System.Drawing.Image ImageFile = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream);
            Bitmap btmFile = new Bitmap(ImageFile, 1366, 768);
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
            stream.Position = 0;
            switch (ImageFormat)
            {
                case "jpg":
                    btmFile.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                    break;
                case "png":
                    btmFile.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
                    break;
                case "gif":
                    btmFile.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
                    break;
            }
            Stream fs = stream;
            BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
            Byte[] bytes = br.ReadBytes((Int32)fs.Length);
```

it works fine but the problem is when i am uploading animated GIF when restored back to image viewer the frames are gone and so does the animation

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resize an animated gif image using C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/539034/how-to-resize-an-animated-gif-image-using-c)

Comment: This problem is happening only in IE, correct?