# Resizing animated Gifs in PowerShell

Tags: .net, powershell, image-resizing, system.drawing

I'm trying to write a helper function in PowerShell that takes an image and resizes it.

This is easy enough for static images, but I'm having trouble with Gifs. If I use the same logic on animated images (>1 frame) the result is that only the first (active) frame is produced.

I've searched for hours and ran through multiple attempts to no avail (or simply code that resulted in glitched or all-black images).

I'm writing this in something self-contained and so I can't rely on any external imaging libraries (like imagemagick) except for whatever is available to PowerShell by default, like .NET.

Here's what I'm thinking:

```
function Resize-Image {
    param (
        [System.Drawing.Image]$originalImage,
        [int]$newHeight,
        [int]$newWidth
    )

    # If it's a Gif
    if ($originalImage.RawFormat.Guid -eq [System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat]::Gif.Guid) {

        # Get dimension and frame count
        $dimension = $originalImage.FrameDimensionsList[0]
        $frameCount = $originalImage.GetFrameCount($dimension)

        # Create a memory stream to use here?


        # Resize each frame and push into new bitmap
        foreach($frameIndex in 0..($frameCount-1)) {
            # Go to the frame in the original image
            [void]$originalImage.SelectActiveFrame($dimension, $frameIndex)
            
            # How do I now take the active frame of $originalImage and push into a Gif?
            # I assume I use some encoders and use a combination of .Save and .SaveAdd, but nothing has worked or not resulted in GDI+ errors
        }

    }
    # If it's not a Gif
    else {
        # Just resize ?
        $resizedImage = New-Object System.Drawing.Bitmap -ArgumentList $originalImage, $newWidth, $newHeight
    }

    return $resizedImage
}
```

I can already detect if the image is a Gif, but how, in my `foreach`, can I resize each active frame from `$originalImage` and push it into a brand new bitmap that I can return at the end? I'd also like to preserve alpha/transparency.

Comment: Instead of trying to reinvent the wheel you might find it easier if you use a library that can do the hard work for you: https://www.nuget.org/packages/PhotoSauce.MagicScaler and https://stackoverflow.com/a/72517882/15339544

Comment: I 100% agree, but I'm aiming to achieve this as part of a self-contained PowerShell module - unless there's a way that a PS module can have dependencies a la npm 

Comment: I don't see whats stopping you. There are a bunch of PowerShell modules which are wrappers of external libraries, i.e. ImportExcel: https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel/blob/master/ImportExcel.psd1#L3 is a wrapper of EPPlus: https://github.com/EPPlusSoftware/EPPlus

Comment: Oh is it possible to "require" an external module in a way that itnwould be automatically installed for users of my module? If so, is there an official way of adding dependencies or are we talking some Install-Module commands within my module that installs another dependency? Because I would much prefer to not reinvent the wheel!